# possible unhadled promise rejection (id: 0) typeError 0,_jwtDecode.default is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: react-native, jwt

When installing jwt-decode to decode the access token of a user in my React-Native application, we encounter the following error. How could this be fixed, is the library updated and/or the code?

Code:

```
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

export function hasExpiredToken(token) {
const data = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(data);
return false;
}
```

Error: possible unhadled promise rejection (id: 0) typeError 0,_jwtDecode.default is not a function (it is undefined)

Thank you

If we do a console log of the token, it returns the previously generated token correctly, so it's not a token assignment issue.

Comment: Change your import to ```import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";```

Comment: Please read the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode